# What will be the SQL Query for search function?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say, someone search for `Android Tricks`, now I want to fetch all rows that contain `Android` and `Tricks` word. (It does not matter, if they are together or their order).

I saw this article: [SQL Like Operator by W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

But I cannot find anything, that can help me.

What will be the full query?

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ???????????
```

Comment: You would appear to want a full text search.  Start with the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html.

Comment: Row or column? Do you want to search in all columns or in a specific column?

Comment: You can also do `column_name LIKE '%Android%' OR column_name LIKE '%Tricks'`. However, the fulltext search would likely be a better solution.

Comment: Really !! You didn't find anything that can help?

watch out this line.. 
-> `WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%or%' Finds any values that have "or" in any position`

Comment: Column sir @Pred